# Order of antipode in Sweedler's Hopf Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, hopf-algebras

I'm learning the basics of Hopf Algebras, and I've found an example that I'm not able to follow, [Sweedler's Hopf Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweedler%27s_Hopf_algebra).

In this Hopf Algebra, we have $g^2 = 1$, $x^2 = 0$, $xg = -gx$, so that in particular $g^{-1} = g$. Then the antipode $\sigma$ is defined by $g \mapsto g, x \mapsto -gx$. This is fine, except I have read (in Fundamentals of Hopf Algebras, by Robert G. Underwood) that in this example $\sigma$ has order $4$, which I'm struggling to follow, as it seems to me $\sigma$ has order $2$.

If we try:
$$(\sigma \circ \sigma)(x) = \sigma(\sigma(x)) = \sigma(-gx) = \sigma(xg)$$

Then (this is possibly where I'm going wrong) I assume we have that $\sigma(xg) = \sigma(x\cdot g) = \sigma(x) \cdot \sigma(g)$. In which case:

$$\sigma(x) \cdot \sigma(g) = -gx \cdot g = xg \cdot g = xg^2 = x$$

So $\sigma$ has order $2$. So my question is, why does my book claim that it has order $4$ (or: what have I done wrong)?

Comment: I may be wrong, but isn't the antipode often an *anti*homomorphism? Implying
$$\sigma^2(x)=\sigma(xg)=\sigma(g)\sigma(x)=g\cdot(-gx)=-x.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike the coproduct or the counit, the antipode is generally not a morphism of algebras. Often it's actually an antihomomorphism, i.e. $\sigma(ab) = \sigma(b) \sigma(a)$, but here we don't know that (yet).

The Wikipedia article doesn't say what $\sigma(xg)$ is, but we can find it. *(Apparently you have a different convention from the Wikipedia article, since you wrote $\sigma(x) = -gx$ but Wikipedia has $\sigma(x) = -xg$. I use Wikipedia's convention but you can reverse everything if you want, you also need to change the coproduct if you want to keep your antipode.)* First compute:
$$\Delta(xg) = \Delta(x) \cdot \Delta(g) = (1 \otimes x + x \otimes g) \cdot (g \otimes g) = g \otimes xg + xg \otimes g.$$
Then apply $\sigma \otimes 1$ to this, and multiply to get
$$\mu((\sigma \otimes 1))(\Delta(xg)) = \mu(g \otimes xg + \sigma(xg) \otimes 1) = gxg + \sigma(xg) = -g^2x + \sigma(xg) = -x + \sigma(xg).$$

But by definition of the antipode, this has to be equal to $\varepsilon(xg) \cdot 1 = 0$, hence $\sigma(xg) = x$. Now we get:
$$\sigma(\sigma(x)) = \sigma(-xg) = - x.$$

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea how to calculate $\sigma (gx)$ if it wasn't a morphism, so thank you for illustrating that (you're right, the definition in my book is a little different, and instead defines comultiplication by $\Delta  (x) = x \otimes 1 + g \otimes x$ - I've worked through this and satisfied myself that it works). Just to clarify - I believe there's a typo in your first line, should it be $g \otimes xg + xg \otimes 1$?

Comment: @Uzai Glad I could help. You're right, it was a typo, I miscopied from my paper...